# Matching user interests with content (based on tags)

Tags: php, sql, tags, comparison, recommendation-engine

I have a lot of content items stored in the database and I know which tags a user is interested to. Alice, for example, shows interest in tags like "healthcare", "sports" and "social". Each content items contains one or more tags. How would I match these in order to recommend new content to Alice?

Consider these basic database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `content_tag` (
   `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `item_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
   `tag_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tag` (
   `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And I have Alice's interests alongside with a (relevance) score, which act like weights:

```
array:3 [
    'healthcare' => 2.20
    'sports' => 1.30
    'socal' => 0.5
]
```

How would you approach this?

Is there a way to use an algorithm for this, like the cosine simularity, or is this only ment for sentences?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Will the score act as a "weight" in sorting the results?

Comment: You could checkout MySQL's [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function (for custom sorting based on the interest scoring). It should work in an `ORDER BY` as well.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The `FIELD` function looks very promising. I will look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find similarities between Alice and items and then sort them. So, most similar n items will be recommended.

One of the similarity metrics is cosine similarity (as you suggest) and works like follows;

For each item you can create a vector by using tags. As far as I understand your items don't have scores so values of item vectors will be 0 or 1. Each value will represent one tag for the particular item.

Item representation;

**[0,0,1,1,0,0]** -> Lets say First value represents 'healthcare', second one is for sports and last tag is for tag5. This item does not have tag5 so its value is **0**

And users also have vectors which is similar to items. 
For instance Alice's vector is;
**[2.20,1.30,0.5,0,0,0]**

After creating vectors you can compute similarity (e.g by using cosine similarity.)

Note that **size of each user and item vectors equals to number of all tags in the system.**
In this example there are 6 distinct tags in the system.